# NPE when invoking a method

Tags: java, android, reflection, methods

For deleting the app data i am trying to use reflection but getting NPE when invoking method

```
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageManager");
Method method = myClass.getMethod("clearApplicationUserData", String.class,IPackageDataObserver.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
Log.v("info",method.getName());
Object c = myClass .newInstance();
method.invoke(c,"com.example.android.apis",null);  //NPE
```

`clearApplicationUserData` return nothing and take two parameters `String` and `IPackageDataObserver`.

Am i passing the correct parameters?

Or How can i solve the problem ?

StackTrace while debugging.

```
 01-31 17:50:07.125: V/info(969): clearApplicationUserData
 01-31 17:50:26.305: D/dalvikvm(969): newInstance failed: p0 i1 [0 a1
 01-31 17:50:26.305: W/System.err(969): java.lang.InstantiationException: android.content.pm.IPackageManager
 01-31 17:50:26.305: W/System.err(969):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 01-31 17:50:26.315: W/System.err(969):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
 01-31 17:50:26.325: W/System.err(969):     at f.c.v.ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.onCreate(ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.java:52)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 17:50:26.355: W/System.err(969):  at           android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-31 17:50:26.355: W/System.err(969):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-31 17:50:26.365: W/System.err(969):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-31 17:50:26.365: W/System.err(969):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-31 17:50:26.375: W/System.err(969):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 17:50:26.375: W/System.err(969):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 17:50:26.385: W/System.err(969):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-31 17:50:26.385: W/System.err(969):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 17:50:26.395: W/System.err(969):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 17:50:26.395: W/System.err(969):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-31 17:50:26.405: W/System.err(969):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

01-31 17:50:26.405: W/System.err(969):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

and Full stacktrace.

```
 01-31 17:26:38.285: E/AndroidRuntime(920): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
 01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{f.c.v/f.c.v.ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
1-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at f.c.v.ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.onCreate(ClearUserDataUsingInterfaceActivity.java:57)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-31 17:26:38.295: E/AndroidRuntime(920):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what's `deleteClass`?  Show us the stacktrace.

Comment: show us the stacktrace.  Is the NPE being thrown inside `clearApplicationUserData`? It's most likely that it does not support null as a parameter.

Comment: so no NPE at all actually, you're getting InstantiationException as you are trying to instantiate and call methods on an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPackageManager` is an interface( as suggested by the 'I' prefix). You cannot instantiate an interface via reflection.

I'm guessing you've meant `android.content.pm.PackageManager`

Comment: if i change to method.invoke(myClass,"com.example.android.apis",new IPackageDataObserver.Stub() {
       
       public void onRemoveCompleted(String packageName, boolean succeeded)
         throws RemoteException {
        Log.v("info","sucess");
        
       }
      });  then i am getting exception that `object is not an instance of the class`

Comment: You should change `Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("android.content.pm.IPackageManager");` as IPackageManager is an interface. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance() and you'll see why you are getting instantiationException.

Comment: how to access  these methods defined in IPackageMnager.aidl

Comment: by instantiating a class that implements the IPackageManager interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems like you should call myClass.newInstance() and not deleteClass.newInstance()
2. Make sure that clearApplicationUserData() method knows to handle null values for IPackageDataObserver.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What is `deleteClass`? Shouldn't you be trying to invoke your method on `myClass`?